# wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to quit

Tags: nvidia, centos7

After installing Nvidia Driver to Centos , the boot screen pop out this error 
wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to quit. It remains there forever. Alt-F3/F2/F4/F5 still works for me but i need the Gui Interfaces. How should i do it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason i getting this error is due to my NVIDIA Quadro K2200 Graphic card. 
My monitor had only VGA display, displaying it with onboard VGA, it prompt the error.  when i changed it to a Monitor with a DVI. It succeed boot into the OS. So, what i think the problem that is causing the problem is the signaling issue. 
The NVIDIA card cannot change the digital signaling to  analog signal.